# How to get the bootstrap popup box in square box

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to get the bootstrap  popup box in square box, At present it is in Rectangular shape, But I need square box ..Please help in this Thanks in Advance...

Example:

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" (click)="c('Save click')">Save</button>
            &nbsp;
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" (click)="c('Save click')">Cancel</button>
        </div>

    </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the height and width equally same, you can make a class in the css and assign that to the modal div.

```
   .myCustomModal {
        height: 100px ;
         width: 100px;
    }
```